# jQuery Facebox plugin: Focus the popup appearance

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebox

I have an HTML page with facebox popup.

This page contains many links and forms, and the popup contains one form.
What I want is, when I open the popup, using only keyboard's buttons, to go directly to the form's inputs of the popup with 'tab' button.

Here is a fiddle --> **http://jsfiddle.net/tk1jagpb/**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox()
})
```

```css
.popup {
  background-color: mistyrose;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#info" rel="facebox">Click to display</a></p>

<div id="info" style="display: none;">
  <p>Popup div</p>
  <p><input type="text" value = "" /></p>
  <p><input type="text" value = "" /></p>
  <p><input type="text" value = "" /></p>
  <p><input type="text" value = "" /></p>
</div>

<p><input type="text" value = "" /></p>
<p><input type="text" value = "" /></p>
<p><input type="text" value = "" /></p>
```

If it were so, I might use the keyboard without having to click the popup box... It would save my time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen for the ['reveal.facebox' event](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) which is fired just after the facebox is shown. 
Once the facebox is shown, just focus the first input field.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
    $(document).bind('reveal.facebox', function() {
        $('.popup input:first').focus();
    });
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works for this case, but if I want to do this for all popups of my website, sometimes i have select, or buttons. Can I do it in general ??

Comment: I think it should work for the general case just as well. Maybe you'll need to modify the selector to '.popup:visible input:first' to make sure you select only the active popup

Comment: no, it does not work for popups with no inputs, just select for exemple, i need something like : $('.popup input:first' , 'select:first'  ).focus();

Comment: You can use the following selector: $('.popup').find('input[type=text],textarea,select').filter(':visible:first').focus()