# How to focus facebox when popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebox

how to focus the facebox when popup ? anyone knows who use the facebox ?
here is my codes. I have my facebox.js and facebox.css

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript: jQuery.facebox({ ajax:'add_actual_amount.phpcvoucherid=<?php echo $listcvoucher[$count]["cvoucher_id"];?>'})">
   <img border="0" src="img/peso.png"  width="20" height="20" />
</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Facebox plugin: Focus the popup appearance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542023/jquery-facebox-plugin-focus-the-popup-appearance)

Answer (score 0):

I just remove the href.

```
<a onClick="javascript: jQuery.facebox({ajax:'add_actual_amount.phpcvoucherid=<?php echo $listcvoucher[$count]["cvoucher_id"];?>'})">
<img border="0" src="img/peso.png"  width="20" height="20" />
</a>
```